# How to choose the right javascript framework and how to get started?

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, angularjs, meteor

its my first post on stack so I'm excited for each answer.

I have a really big problem in choosing the right javascript framework. Just some personal information, I know the basics of javaScript, I can write jQuery and of course I know HTML5 and CSS3. But I want to jump into server side applications, as many others too, I guess. I'm reading since months in the web about all the different frameworks but it's just so complicated to decide for one.

Some days ago I started to try angularJs, but for some reason I didn't really understand it, as it goes deeper, because I don't really understand the documentation and as far as I searched, there are not much videocasts out there. I can learn much better with videos.

Then I switched to meteor.js but their documentation is even more complicated and there are also not much videos out there. While reading about meteor I headed over to node.js, because it was said, its easier understandable if I understand node.js. But until I understand node.js there is much time lost. I know I have to learn it, but I just want to start with a client side framework which easily connects then with node.js.

My basic intention for now is, just to start with a real basic todo app, just for myself to learn it and maybe add more and more features later. Some day I want to go on and try another app and another etc. It's a long way. But I can't choose a framework for it. I want something, which is pretty open to different use cases, wether its a small or a big app. Just in case for the future. But mostly when I'm reading about a framework, they also say something about commonJS, underscore.js etc. and it just confuses me, because I always think I have to learn all that stuff.

So what's the best way to start? Should I just go back to Angular and try it further? Should I just try to write it on my own and look into the docs when I need something, or should I read the complete doc first? Same for meteor. And I also have backbone always in my mind, if its maybe a better one. This area is so overwhelming to start, so what's your experience? How did you start and whats the best way? I dont want to loose more time for senseless reading with no decision.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It looks like you do not have an idea "why" you want to learn a Javascript framework. It sounds to me "I want to learn any javascript framework which can achieve any task, now and in the future". I am not sure if anyone can give a clear answer to that. From my experience, it's more the way you have a problem and take a look how to solve this best. In you case I would try to think about your TODO-list application and then choose which technology (server-side and client-side) to use. If needed, you can learn a framework which does the task best for you then.

Comment: One other thing - you write you want to jump into server side applications. So you will need to learn a server-side programming language like Java, C# or PHP.

Comment: try this:  [todomvc](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/)

Comment: @w4rumy - Or JavaScript.. Using node.js..

Comment: angularjs official videos http://www.youtube.com/user/angularjs. But remember that angularjs is "client" side framework. You still need to write all the server-side apis

Comment: LEARN [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org) Easy syntax. AMAZING documentation. Disregard everything else for now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Choosing a JavaScript framework is not an easy task - there are a great many of them out there, and they vary considerably in terms of quality, features and maturity. I would recommend visiting the [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/) site, which demonstrates the same applications - a simple to-do list - implemented with various different frameworks.

It offers the following guidance on how to make the selection that is right for you:

> Once you've downloaded the latest release and played around with the
>   apps, you'll want to decide on a specific framework to try out.
>
> Study the syntax required for defining models, views and (where
>   applicable) controllers and classes in the frameworks you're
>   interested in and try your hand at editing the code to see how it
>   feels using it first-hand.
>
> Please ensure that if you're happy with this, you do spend more time
>   investigating the framework (including reading the official docs, the
>   source and its complete feature list). There's often a lot more to a
>   framework than what we present in our examples.

Comment: I am also damn confused on which Javascript framework to Learn. I am currently building a website with Metro Look and Feel, mostly involves only Client Side Interaction, No Server Side and it's Single Page & doing it in ASP.NET SPA template. Its available in all JS frameworks but to do it right, i need to learn a JS framework as i think, but which one to i am still confused but talked with Some Other Folks, they suggested about Angular.

Answer (score 0):

I am putting *node.js* through its paces right now, without using any of the frameworks. I am ignoring the frameworks right now because I want to working out what I can and cannot do wiith just *node.js*  So far, I have gotten *node.js* to respond with a **hello** statement, a JSON statement, the contents of a text file including a rendered HTML file, next on the list is a record from a Mongodb database. I also broke an HTML page into a header file, a body file and a footer file and I used promises from the *q.js* library to render the whole file HTML page as a single unit. Out of necessity, I am rendering all HTML pages as dynamic but I am researching into rendering static pages.

I also implemented *node.js* with SSL the day before yesterday, I worked out how to export *node.js* to heroku and I need to implement redirection from http to https.

Once I am comfortably if not thoroughly - "thoroughly" might be overkill - familiar with *node.js* without the frameworks, I'll be adding frameworks such as *express.js* and *socket.io* one at a time and see what I can do with each of them separately. I believe that this one-framework-at-a-time onion layer approach is the surest and least time-consuming way of mastering *node.js* with a reasonable level of confidence. And the approach is realistic in its doability because we are talking about only three or four frameworks.

I am surprised that you never explored *bootstrap.js* at the front end - at this point, I can do *bootstrap.js* in my sleep - and that you never looked into AJAX calls, which allow asynchronous communication with the back end.